# Enumerator for Word and Halting Problem

Tags: formal-languages, computability, formal-grammars, decision-problem, enumeration

in theoretical computer science I learned for every recursive enumerable language there would be an enumerator and a grammar. So since word problem and halting problem are recursively enumerable, I was wondering what kind of grammar and enumerator could this be. And let the Wordproblem be  $ L = \{ \langle M, w \rangle | M  \space is \space TM  \space and  \space w \in L(M) \} $ and Halting Problem $ L = \{ \langle M, w \rangle | M  \space is \space TM  \space and  \space M \space halts \space on  \space w\} $

Ok for word problem: since there exists a sequence of $M_i$ I would start with $M_1$ and find all words for this TM and give them out. So if I have any TM is there a possibility to give all words out which are accepted by this TM? I probably would have to give all $w_i$ to it and compute the first i words for i steps, then i+1 words for i+1 steps and so on for a sequence of computable words $w_1, w_2,.. \in \Sigma^*  $ Or maybe something like DFS on all configurations. This really sounds like that only for one TM this could go on forever. So I would need to start the second TM for the same period of time after a while... Seems as if something similiar could work for Halting Problem. Do you have any more refined thoughts on this one?

Greets,

Felix

Comment: Did you check a proof? THe proof I've seen is pretty constructive: https://www.cs.utexas.edu/~cline/ear/automata/CS341-Fall-2004-Packet/1-LectureNotes/25-TuringMachinesHandout.pdf

Comment: yeah I spent more time understanding the proof as well. So finding the grammar comes more down to finding the TM and what the TM, since once we have the TM we just use construction rules. Finding a TM seems more intuitve.

Comment: What's the word problem? Can you write or add a reference to a formal definition?

Comment: added the definition. sorry didn´t found this one over google and wikipedia linked me to unprecise english sites from german definition. what is the acurate name for it?

Comment: So $w$ is just some fixed word, given as a parameter of the problem? In that case the same strategy in my answer also works for the word problem. (Just simulate $T$ with input $w$)

Answer (score 1):

Let $\Sigma = \{0, 1\}$. Clearly $\Sigma^*$ is enumerable. For the word problem you can proceed as follows.

- For each pair $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}_+^2$ in dovetail fashion:

  - Let $w_i$ be the $i$-th word in $\Sigma^*$.
  - Check whether $w_i$ encodes a valid Turing machine $T$ (w.r.t. some fixed encoding). If not skip to the next iteration.
  - Simulate the Turing machine $T$ with input $w$ for at most $j$ steps.
  - If $T$ halts at the end of the $j$-th step, output $T$.

For the Halting problem you can do as follows:

- For each pair $(i, j, k) \in \mathbb{N}_+^3$ in dovetail fashion:

  - Let $w_i$ be the $i$-th word in $\Sigma^*$.
  - Let $w_j$ be the $j$-th word in $\Sigma^*$.
  - Check whether $w_i$ encodes a valid Turing machine $T$ (w.r.t. some fixed encoding). If not skip to the next iteration.
  - Simulate the Turing machine $T$ with input $w_j$ for at most $k$ steps.
  - If $T$ halts at the end of the $k$-th step, output $\langle T, w_j \rangle$.

Comment: okay seems legit though for constructing an enumerator for the halting problem wouldn´t you have to run $M_i = w_i$ over all $w_1,w_2,... \in \Sigma^*$?

Comment: Depends on the exact definition of the halting problem. I'm enumerating the set of Turing machines $T$ such that $T$ eventually halts on empty input. Are you interested in all the pairs $\langle T, w \rangle$ such that $T$ halts on $w$ instead?

Comment: yes I was thinking about pairs of $ \langle M, w \rangle $ didn´t consider details in definition since I thought these problems are universally well known though it really makes a difference. What do you ecactly mean by $N_+$ what is the plus required for?

Comment: also regarding any pair $(i,j) \in \mathbb{N}_+^2$ wouldn´t you have to define in which order the TM´s $M_i$ are being simulated. Maybe we could use some kind of diagonalisation argument for this one and define third axes for all pairs over $w_1, w_2,...$

Comment: I just wanted to exclude $0$ (simulate a Turing machine for $0$ steps doesn't make much sense). Also I'm assuming that the first word in the enumeration of $\Sigma^*$ is $w_1$ and not $w_0$.

Comment: What do you mean define in which order the TM´s $M_i$ are being simulated? That depends on the enumeration of the words of $\Sigma^*$ you are considering. An easy way considers them in order of length, and within the same length in lexicographic order. That is: empty string, then $0$, then $1$, then $00$, $01$, $10$, $11$, $011$, etc.

Comment: with order I meant more like defining in which way the pairs are being ordere i.e. you first start wird (1,1,1), (1, 1, 2) (1, 1, 3), (1, 2, 2,) (1, 2, 3). I meant this with  diagonalisation argument for example how $ \mathbb{N} $ can be ordered. Or is it enough to assume that some kind of order on $(i, j) $ or $ (i, j, k)$ exists?

Comment: I'm looking at the pairs (and triples) in dovetail fashion. So first $(1,1)$, then all the pairs that sum to $3$, i.e., $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$, then all the pairs that sum to $4$, i.e., $(1,3)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,1)$, etc. See e.g., [this figure](https://blog.wolfram.com/data/uploads/2015/09/Enumerating-the-rational-numbers.png) which is about enumeration rationals but uses the same idea.